# Use PHP Regular Expression to Fix Invalid HTML

Tags: php, regex

I want to fix HTML code that does not have the equal sign on the `class` attribute. The code bellow checks the brackets only, and would remove the `REPLACE_ME` class and put `class="`. Here is the code:

```
<?php

$mystring = <<<'EOT'

<div class"REPLACE_ME" id="my_id">this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced</div>
this REPLACE_ME cannot be replaced

EOT;

echo preg_replace('~<[^>]*\KREPLACE_ME(?=[^>]*?>)~', 'class="', $mystring);
```

I want to be able to fix my `class` attribute equal-sign. How can I do this?

Comment: What about `str_replace('class"', 'class="', $string);`?

Comment: It would work but I wanted more functionality

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean? Are there instances where `class"` would be valid?

Comment: Why did you leave out `REPLACE_ME` in the replacement string if you want to keep it?

Comment: I know how to use `str_replace('class"', 'class="', $string);`, thus I wanted more functionality, be able to fix a class in an html tag where there are brackets. Fix all brackets.

Comment: You need to put `<[^>]*` in a capture group so that you can copy it into the replacement.